# Select rows as columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need some help with simple, I guess, select query. I am not a SQL expert, so I am not even sure how to name this query, and which keywords are used in such operation. Let's say I have two relational tables:

```
table foo:

id | name
---------
1  | foo
2  | oof
3  | ofo
4  | fob
5  | bof


table bar:

id | feature
------------
1  | bar
1  | arb
1  | rab
3  | 333
4  | ddd
4  | eee
```

And desired result is:

```
id | name | feature | feature | feature
----------------------------------------
1  | foo  | bar     | arb     | rab
3  | ofo  | 333     |         |
4  | foo  | ddd     | eee     |
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install tablefunc module. Then you can write query like

```
SELECT * 
FROM crosstab('SELECT id, name, feature 
               FROM foo 
               INNER JOIN bar on foo.id = bar.id') 
AS ct(id integer, name text, feature_1 text, feature_2 text, feature_3 text);
```

additional info http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tablefunc.html